# Finding my codepen tribute page in google search

Tags: html, css, google-search, codepen

I have made a tribute page project with codepen for freecodecamp , when i search for it in google i can’t find it. Is there any tips or modification i can do ? thank you .
[https://codepen.io/macdeesh/pen/RwjbXBZ][1]

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Why aren't search engines indexing my content?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/43350/why-arent-search-engines-indexing-my-content)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to **host** your site:

[how to host static site to github](https://pages.github.com/)

or you have some free site hosting platform

- GitHub Pages
- Netlify
- Vercel
- Firebase Hosting.

or you can do like this:

click on below button on your codepen :

[image: codepen]

this will open your page in new tab, it will be full screen.